# Cannot implement if then logic to sql code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas

Wanted to change the SAS code to SQL, but did not know which way
should I follow, but I tried with case when, it gave me error.

SAS Code:

```
length list_of_Fields $400.;
list_of_Fields = "";

if missing(column_a)        eq 1 then do; if calc_of_count <= limit_of_Count then list_of_Fields = catx(" ;", calculation_of_columnName, "Company1"); calc_of_count + 1; end;
if missing(column_b)        eq 1 then do; if calc_of_count <= limit_of_Count then list_of_Fields = catx(" ;", calculation_of_columnName, "Company2"); calc_of_count + 1; end;


if list_of_Fields eg "" then list_of_Fields = &strNone
```

SQL CODE:

```
case 
    when column_a is null then case when calc_of_count <= limit_of_Count then ist_of_Fields = catx(" ;", calculation_of_columnName, "Company1") 
    when column_b is null then case when calc_of_count <= limit_of_Count then list_of_Fields = catx(" ;", calculation_of_columnName, "Company2")
```

Unfortunately was not able to finish it accordingly, could you please help me to find the way?

Comment: Don't add tags for products not involved.

Comment: catx I guess is sas equivalent of concat, every case needs and END

Comment: jarlh, could you please tell me which product is not involved?

Comment: @KananMehdizade it's *you* who should tell us which product *is* involved. MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? They are different databases with different syntax. *All* databases use extensions to the SQL standard while *none* of them fully implements it beyond basic compliance - it's just too complicated

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, SQL Server is a product

Comment: As in the SAS code you increase `calc_of_count` and use it in your next evaluation, this is an iterative process. This is not easily done in SQL. Maybe with some recursive query, but I would rather stick to a programming language. But you are only showing a small part of code. What is it for? Maybe the overall task is easily achievable in SQL while the sub part isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the following way:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (column_a is null AND calc_of_count <= limit_of_Count) THEN ist_of_Fields = CONCAT(" ;", calculation_of_columnName, "Company1") 
    WHEN (column_b is null AND calc_of_count <= limit_of_Count) THEN list_of_Fields = CONCAT(" ;", calculation_of_columnName, "Company2") 
    ELSE list_of_Fields = &strNone
END
```

You can also try IF CLAUSE in below format:

```
IF(condn, TRUE_STATEMENT, FALSE_STATEMENT);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, could you please tell me where should I code this part? calc_of_count + 1;

Comment: `THEN ist_of_Fields = CONCAT(" ;", calculation_of_columnName, "Company1")`? A `CASE` expression cannot return a boolean result in T-SQL, it returns a Scalar Value. This will only error.

Comment: You can try -  SELECT @calc_of_count:=@calc_of_count+1 calc_of_count, 
CASE WHEN (column_a is null AND calc_of_count <= limit_of_Count) THEN ist_of_Fields = CONCAT(" ;", calculation_of_columnName, "Company1") 
    WHEN (column_b is null AND calc_of_count <= limit_of_Count) THEN list_of_Fields = CONCAT(" ;", calculation_of_columnName, "Company2") 
    ELSE list_of_Fields = &strNone END FROM YOUR_TABLE_1,   (SELECT `@calc_of_count`:= 0) AS CalcCount;